# I've Made a Tagable Mistake

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process, spelling

So I felt like I needed [this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2642059+[zero-intialization]) in half the questions that I was asking, and I went to all the trouble of defining it. But I've learned that I cannot spell.

That should have been "zero-initialization". It does make me feel better that a bunch of other people can't spell either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initalization

What happens to tags like these that need to be renamed? And how do I go about correcting this?

Comment: Just remove it from the questions so it can be automatically deleted.

Comment: 1) Re-tagging -> The old tag without questions will die 2) create/vote for synonym so initalization will be initialization.

Comment: Surely someone internally at SO could go into the database and manually rename the tag, instead of having to go through retagging.

Comment: Just use i11n, then you don't annoy z/s people either.

Comment: This post if the story of my life: *`I've learned that I cannot spell`*, *`It does make me feel better that a bunch of other people can't spell either`* :D Also you might wanna check out the "static-initalization" tag maybe that's the tag you're looking for.

Comment: There are over 2000 questions using `javascipt` (and in some of them, the typo is the crux of the question); there are over 5000 questions using `programing`.  Misspelling is rife!  (And it wouldn't be surprising to find that mispelled is mispeled too.)

Comment: @Mango "This post **if** the story of my life". :D

Comment: @krillgar I had not realised :O :D my grammar and spelling mistakes make me cringe :D

Comment: Maybe common misspellings like this are worth a synonym? | @krillgar it's very rude to point out someone's speech impediment like that!

Comment: @Mango [Zero-Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) is different from [Static-Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) (independent of spelling.)

Comment: @JonathanMee: Zero initialization is one of the steps of static initialization.  But you're right that you can't blindly substitute the latter, since zero initialization is also performed for value initialization.  However, there's no need for [tag:zero-initialization] in the context of C++, because tags already exist for both static initialization and value initialization, and those are more relevant.

Comment: Is this really a tag?  Can someone be an expert on zero-initialization?

Comment: @OrangeDog That tag was burninated.

Comment: Sadly I cannot create a synonym because I do not have the required 5 points in the tag. I don't think it's reasonable for me to retag someone else's question with this tag. I've looked through the [tag:initalization] and [tag:C++] questions and added improved answers where possible. Is there anything else that can be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A tag that isn't used by any questions will get automatically deleted. Simply remove the tag from all your questions and it will disappear after a day or so.

That being said, are you sure you aren't actually looking for [static-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-initialization)? This is the correct term in C and C++. For example, C++ classes with static storage duration will have their constructors executed before main() is called - this is part of static initialization.

While setting the contents of something returned from malloc etc to zero is *not* initialization, it is run-time assignment.

Comment: Mee and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization seem to think "zero-initialization" is the term I was looking for?

Comment: @JonathanMee: No, it isn't.  Because it's too broad.  As that page you linked points out, zero initialization can happen either in static initialization or value initialization or aggregate initialization.  Please tag with one of those more specific cases, since they act quite differently.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't mind deleting the tag, but first can you give me a more detailed explaination of why that's necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37732000/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee cpprefererence.com is rather notorious, please refer to the standard instead. To clarify, here's from C++11 3.6.2: "Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
before any other initialization takes place." /--/ "Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called _static initialization_; all other initialization is _dynamic initialization_." Static initialization is a formal term in the standard. Since zero-initialization is part of static initialization, I don't see why we need two tags.

Comment: cppreference offers a substantially more complete picture. You'd have to additionally quote at least [dcl.init]p8.2 where value initialization delegates to zero initialization and [dcl.init.string]p3 where elements of char arrays are zero-initialized. Although it is a valid question what kind of zero-init the OP meant.